# Flush output to drake::log()

Tags: drake

Is there a way to get `drake::log()` messages to flush to output?  I'm finding that in my use case the difference between the time a log message appears and the the time stamp of the message is on the order of minutes and I'd like a little faster logging response.

Answer (score 1):

By default, each log message should already be flushed:

https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.5.0/include/spdlog/sinks/stdout_sinks-inl.h#L32

There must be something else going on in your configuration.

Comment: I'm calling the code that does the logging from a Jupyter notebook. Could that be interfering?

Comment: Ah.  For pydrake, logs go to https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html.  I don't know off the top of my head when/how that flushes.

Comment: Hmm.  It's a `import pydrake.common` that sets up logging.  It _should_ be the case that that always precedes any use of Drake C++ logging, but you might try importing that specifically and see if it helps.